# About using elementary row operations and finding the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to try finding the eigenvalues of the following matrix using only elementary row operations:

A =\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&3\\3&-5&3\\6&-6&4\end{bmatrix}

The elementary row operations performed on this matrix are as follows:

R2-3R1

R3-6R1

R3-3R2

and I got an upper triangular matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&3\\0&4&-6\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}

From here I concluded that the matrix A has eigen values : $\lambda = 4$ with algebraic multiplicity of 2 and $\lambda = 1$ with algebraic multiplicity of 1.

However, the solutions I have gotten is $\lambda = -2$ with algebraic multiplicity of 2 and $\lambda = 4$ with algebraic multiplicity of 1. What went wrong? Shouldn't the eigen values remain the same even after performing the elementary row operation that does not change the determinant?

Comment: I'm confused.  The row operations sometimes change the determinant (e.g. scaling a row), and when they don't they leave the determinant of $A$ alone.  But that's different from the determinant of $\lambda I - A$.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that, after applying elementary row operations, the eigenvalues remain the same. That's not true. Consider, for instance, the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Its only eigenvalue is $1$. Now, add to the second row the first row times $-1$. You will get $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, whose eigenvalues are $\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$.

Comment: So what elementary row operations should I apply to make sure the eigenvalues of the initial matrix does not change?

Comment: Not many. In general, they *don't* preserve the eigenvalues.

Comment: @brendon you apply row operations to $\lambda I - A$, not $A$.

Comment: @Randall what do you mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So when is it appropriate to perform EROs on a matrix to find its eigenvalues, or do we not perform EROs when trying to find its eigenvalues?

Comment: We do *not* perform elementary row operations to find the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$. However, as Randall suggested, we can perform such operations of $\lambda\operatorname{Id}-A$ since these operations preserve the determinant.